Does enabling OpenGL and 3D Acceleration in a virtual machine compromise its security?
On my VMs (using Virt Manager), I always set the Display Spice settings' Listen Type to None and enable OpenGL. I also enable 3D Acceleration in the Video Virtio settings.
While it's not a miracle, this does improve the speed of the VMs a bit, allowing them to handle video playback and other relatively graphics-intensive operations noticeably better.
However, I am wondering if this affects the security of the VMs in any way, potentially making it easier for a VM escape.
